# How to move the anchor to the top of the div when the screen width is lower than the max-width?

Tags: html, css

I have a page that the view is as below which is the view I want.

[image]

But when I change the size of the device-width, the distance between the anchors are increasing when I give a new value to `line-width` property of anchor tags in media query. And the page is displayed as below:

[image]

I want to learn how the distance of the anchors to remain same when I change the max-width.

Here are the codes:

```css
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 25px;
    color: green;
}

a:hover {
    color: #000;
    background-color: green;
}

.midnav-left {
    position: fixed;
    margin: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}

.upper-content,
.lower-content {
    display: none;
}

.upper-link {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 75px;
}

.upper-content-link {
    width: 200px;
    display: block;
}

.lower-content-link {
    width: 25px;
    display: block;
}

.lower-category .upper-content-link {
    display: inline-block;
}

.upper-category:hover .upper-content,
.lower-category:hover .lower-content {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
}

.upper-category:hover .upper-link,
.lower-category:hover .upper-content-link {
    color: #000;
    background-color: green;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { 
    .midnav-left {
        margin: 25px;
    }
    
    a {
        font-size: 7.5px;
        line-height: 12.5px;
    } 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="tr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>TkJeoLog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./test.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="midnav">
        <div class="midnav-left">
            <div class="upper-category">
                <a class="upper-link" href="#">Dosya</a>
                <div class="upper-content">
                    <a class="upper-content-link" href="#">Aç</a>
                    <a class="upper-content-link" href="#">Kapat</a>
                    <a class="upper-content-link" href="#">Kaydet</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="upper-category">
                <a class="upper-link" href="">Ekle</a>
                <div class="upper-content">
                    <a class="upper-content-link" href="#">Derinlik Bilgisi</a>
                    <a class="upper-content-link" href="#">Muhafaza Borusu Bilgisi</a>
                    <a class="upper-content-link" href="#">Proje Ve Şirket Bilgileri</a>
                    <a class="upper-content-link" href="#">Litoloji Bilgileri</a>
                    <div class="lower-category">
                        <a class="upper-content-link" href="#">Örnek Bilgileri</a>
                        <div class="lower-content">
                            <a class="lower-content-link" href="#">rc</a>
                            <a class="lower-content-link" href="#">spt</a>
                            <a class="lower-content-link" href="#">ud</a>
                            <a class="lower-content-link" href="#">pr</a>
                            <a class="lower-content-link" href="#">pd</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="upper-category">
                <a class="upper-link" href="#">Tuval</a>
                <div class="upper-content">
                    <a class="upper-content-link" href="#">Görüntüle</a>
                    <a class="upper-content-link" href="#">Dışa Aktar</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="upper-category">
                <a class="upper-link" href="#">Ayarlar</a>
                <div class="upper-content">
                    <a class="upper-content-link" href="#">Dil</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="upper-category">
                <a class="upper-link" href="#">Yardım</a>
                <div class="upper-content">
                    <a class="upper-content-link" href="#">Hakkında</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No idea why you have used `display:inline-block` on your `.upper-link` . That's the problem. Change it to `display:block` and increase your `line-height` in your `mediaqueries` till you find the right vertical space.

Comment: When mouse hovers to `.upper-category`, the `.upper-content` should be displayed at the right of the `.upper-link`.

Comment: I don't mean any offense, but your html structure is quite a mess. the normal way to do what you are trying is to use `position:asbolute` for the hidden content and use a list structure. like this: https://jsfiddle.net/xf51mnwt/2/ (but it¡s just my opinion)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Your codes look cleaner than my codes.